# C, Segmentation fault parsing large csv file

Tags: c, csv, segmentation-fault

I wrote a simple program that would open a csv file, read it, make a new csv file, and only write some of the columns (I don't want all of the columns and am hoping removing some will make the file more manageable). The file is 1.15GB, but `fopen()` doesn't have a problem with it. The segmentation fault happens in my while loop shortly after the first progress `printf()`.

I tested on just the first few lines of the csv and the logic below does what I want. The strange section for when `index == 0` is due to the last column being in the form `(xxx, yyy)\n` (the `,` in a comma separated value file is just ridiculous).

Here is the code, the while loop is the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    long size;
    FILE* inF = fopen("allCrimes.csv", "rb");
    if (!inF) {
        puts("fopen() error");
        return 0;
    }
    fseek(inF, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(inF);
    rewind(inF);

    printf("In file size = %ld bytes.\n", size);
    char* buf = malloc((size+1)*sizeof(char));
    if (fread(buf, 1, size, inF) != size) {
        puts("fread() error");
        return 0;
    }
    fclose(inF);
    buf[size] = '\0';

    FILE *outF = fopen("lessColumns.csv", "w");
    if (!outF) {
        puts("fopen() error");
        return 0;
    }

    int index = 0;
    char* currComma = strchr(buf, ',');
    fwrite(buf, 1, (int)(currComma-buf), outF);

    int progress = 0;
    while (currComma != NULL) {
        index++;
        index = (index%14 == 0) ? 0 : index;
        progress++;
        if (progress%1000 == 0) printf("%d\n", progress/1000);

        int start = (int)(currComma-buf);
        currComma = strchr(currComma+1, ',');
        if (!currComma) break;
        if ((index >= 3 && index <= 10) || index == 13) continue;

        int end = (int)(currComma-buf);
        int endMinusStart = end-start;
        char* newEntry = malloc((endMinusStart+1)*sizeof(char));
        strncpy(newEntry, buf+start, endMinusStart);
        newEntry[end+1] = '\0';

        if (index == 0) {
            char* findNewLine = strchr(newEntry, '\n');
            int newLinePos = (int)(findNewLine-newEntry);
            char* modifiedNewEntry = malloc((strlen(newEntry)-newLinePos+1)*sizeof(char));
            strcpy(modifiedNewEntry, newEntry+newLinePos);
            fwrite(modifiedNewEntry, 1, strlen(modifiedNewEntry), outF);
        }
        else fwrite(newEntry, 1, end-start, outF);
    }
    fclose(outF);

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit**: It turned out the problem was that the csv file had `,` in places I was not expecting which caused the logic to fail. I ended up writing a new parser that removes lines with the incorrect number of commas. It removed 243,875 lines (about 4% of the file). I'll post that code instead as it at least reflects some of the comments about `free()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    long size;
    FILE* inF = fopen("allCrimes.csv", "rb");
    if (!inF) {
        puts("fopen() error");
        return 0;
    }
    fseek(inF, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(inF);
    rewind(inF);

    printf("In file size = %ld bytes.\n", size);
    char* buf = malloc((size+1)*sizeof(char));
    if (fread(buf, 1, size, inF) != size) {
        puts("fread() error");
        return 0;
    }
    fclose(inF);
    buf[size] = '\0';

    FILE *outF = fopen("uniformCommaCount.csv", "w");
    if (!outF) {
        puts("fopen() error");
        return 0;
    }

    int numOmitted = 0;
    int start = 0;
    while (1) {
        char* currNewLine = strchr(buf+start, '\n');
        if (!currNewLine) {
            puts("Done");
            break;
        }

        int end = (int)(currNewLine-buf);
        char* entry = malloc((end-start+2)*sizeof(char));
        strncpy(entry, buf+start, end-start+1);
        entry[end-start+1] = '\0';

        int commaCount = 0;
        char* commaPointer = entry;
        for (; *commaPointer; commaPointer++) if (*commaPointer == ',') commaCount++;

        if (commaCount == 14) fwrite(entry, 1, end-start+1, outF);
        else numOmitted++;

        free(entry);
        start = end+1;
    }
    fclose(outF);
    printf("Omitted %d lines\n", numOmitted);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debugging info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`). Use a debugger (e.g. `gdb`). Learn how to use it (backtrace, watchpoints, breakpoints, ....). Test the result of all low level functions (`malloc`, `fwrite`, ....). Use `perror` or `errno` when they fail. Use a memory leak detector like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: On what operating system, with what compiler (and what options) are you coding for?

Comment: You can replace `index++; index = (index%14 == 0) ? 0 : index;` with `index = (index + 1) % 14;`, can't you?  You repeatedly `malloc()` in the `index == 0` section but never `free()` anything; also just before that.  You also don't check that the `malloc()` succeeds.  You probably crash when the `malloc()` fails because you've run out of memory.

Comment: OSX, GCC, and no options? Not sure what you mean with that one

Comment: Have you considered using `strtok()` to split the line on commas?

Comment: you are reading the whole file into memory. instead you could resort to a strictly line-by-line processing

Comment: @collapsar, I did not realize reading in some of a file was an option. Do you mean opening the entire file to `inF` and only assigning `buf` as one line or opening one line to `inF`?

Comment: there is a library function [fgets](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) that reads one line at a time. employing this call, you can iterate over the file content line by line.

Comment: `getline` is more useful and more appropriate than `fgets`.

Comment: I don't understand why the OP keeps asking his question instead of debugging with `gdb`....

Comment: Because I have basically no experience with it. Reading one line at a time seems like a good solution

Comment: @asimes: with respect, that means you should learn. There's a (reasonably) good beginner tutorial here: http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbtoc.html

Comment: The problem described and the solutions provided turned out to be unrelated to the problem. The problem was unexpected formatting in the csv file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're malloc'ing but never freeing. possibly you run out of memomry, one of your mallocs returns `NULL`, and the subsequent call to `str(n)cpy` segfaults.

adding `free(newEntry);`, `free(modifiedNewEntry);` immediately after the respective `fwrite` calls should solve your memory shortage.

also note that inside your loop you compute offsets into the buffer `buf` which contains the whole file. these offsets are held in variables of type `int` whose maximum value on your system may be too small for the numbers you are handling. also note that adding large `int`s  may result in a negative value which is another possible cause of the segfault (negative offsets into buf take you to some address outside the buffer possibly not even readable).

Comment: Adding the lines for freeing still causes a segmentation fault

Comment: Because `malloc` can fail, and you should handle that

Comment: @asimes I don't believe `modifiedNewEntry` is even needed *at all*. And I'm fairly positive `newEntry` isn't needed either. You have all the data in a buffer, and have the offsets for the entities you're writing. `buff` should be enough if you are creative enough.

Comment: @WhozCraig, why's that? I don't want to write what `newEntry` would be when index is 0.

Comment: When I tried testing out the negative numbers from large ints I found that there were negative ints (that was the problem) but they occurred from unexpected `,` in the middle of the csv. At least they are written as `" text , text "`

Answer (score 1):

The [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) function can (and sometimes does) fail.

At least code something like

```
    char* buf = malloc(size+1);
    if (!buf) {
       fprintf(stderr, "failed to malloc %d bytes - %s\n", 
               size+1, strerror(errno));
       exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

And I strongly suggest to clear with `memset(buf, 0, size+1)` the successful result of a `malloc` (or otherwise use `calloc` ....), not only because the following `fread` could fail (which you are testing) but to ease debugging and reproducibility.
and likewise for every other calls to `malloc` or `calloc` (you should *always* test them against failure)....

<sup>Notice that *by definition* `sizeof(char)` is *always* 1. Hence I removed it.</sup>

As others pointed out, you have a [memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) because you don't call `free` appropriately. A tool like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) could help.

You need to **learn how to use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`). Don't forget to compile with all warnings and debugging information (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`). And improve your code till you get no warnings.

<sup>Knowing how to use a debugger is an essential required skill when programming (particularly in C or C++). That debugging skill (and ability to use the debugger) will be useful in every C or C++ program you contribute to.</sup>

BTW, you could read your file line by line with [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) (which can also fail and you should test that).

Comment: Time to learn how to use a debugger like `gdb`. And learning that (how to use a debugger) is essential when coding in C or C++....